# java generics, how to extend from two classes?

Tags: java, generics

I want to have a Class object, but I want to force whatever class it represents to extend class A and also class B.
I can do

```
<T extends ClassA & ClassB>
```

but it is not possible to extend from both classes,  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You can extend from a single class and several interfaces.

Comment: You can't extend from multiple classes because Java doesn't support multiple inheritance of classes, period. This isn't a generics problem.

Comment: thanks for your answer but i need to extend from two classes not a class and several interfaces.

Comment: What about "Java doesn't support multiple inheritance of classes" isn't clear? You *can't* extend from two classes. Full stop. That is something you can't get around, unless the classes are in the same hierarchy, in which case you don't need to extend from two classes.

Comment: if it will be possible to write generics that extends from two classes, you then can't initialize such class, because you can't write class, that meet requirements (java haaven't multiply inheritance)

Comment: Please write a class (say `ClassC`) that compiles and extends the two classes (`ClassA` and `ClassB`) and post it.

Answer (score 4):

In java you cannot have a class which extends from two classes, since it doesn't support multiple inheritance. What you can have, is something like so:

```
public class A
...

public class B extends A
...

public class C extends B
...
```

In your generic signature, you can then specify that `T` must extend `C`: `<T extends C>`.

You could give a look at [`Default Methods`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html) (if you are working with Java 8), which essentially are methods declared within interfaces, and in Java, a class can implement multiple interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

Java does not have multiple inheritance as a design decision, but you may implement multiple interfaces.

As of Java 8 these interfaces may have implementations.

To use multiple classes there are other patterns:

1. If the parent classes are purely intended for that child class, but handle entirely different aspects, and were therefore separated, place them in a single artificial hierarchy. I admit to doing this once.
2. Use delegation; duplicate the API and delegate.
3. Use a lookup/discovery mechanism for very dynamic behaviour.

   public  T lookup(Class klazz);

   This would need an API change, but uncouples classes, and is dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way for this problem is inheritance.

```
public class A { // some codes }

public class B extends A { }

<T extends A>
```